# Entity instance cannot be tracked because another with the same key value is already being tracked. DDD + CQRS + EF Core

Tags: .net, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I am more or less following Microsoft's DDD and CQRS patterns example ([eshopOnContainers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/) app) to build my application.

I have the following main components:

1. Application Layer/PostTransactionService
2. Application Layer/BillClassificationQueries
3. Domain Model Layer/Model classes
4. Repository Layer/TransactionRepository (EF Core)

**Application Layer/PostTransactionService:**

Here, I build my domain model objects which often require domain model instances from "BillingClassificationQueries", for instance, to build a "Transaction" instance I need a "transactionBillClassification" instance like this:

```
var transactionBillClassification = await _billingClassificationQueries.GetBillClassification(command.BillingClassificationId.Value);

var transaction = Transaction.CreateTransactionForChargeOrCredit(
                    account,
                    command.TransactionDate,
                    Enumeration.FromValue<ChargeAction>(command.ChargeActionId),
                    Enumeration.FromValue<ChargeType>(command.ChargeTypeId),
                    new Money(command.AmountPosted),                   
                    transactionBillClassification,
                    parentTransaction);
```

**Application Layer/BillClassificationQueries**

Now, in BillingClassificationQueries class, I use Dapper just for reading data from the database and I map the results directly into Domain Models (I know, I could use View Models instead but I feel I would get same problem), as follwoing:

```
 public async Task<BillClassification> GetBillClassification(int billingClassificationId)
    {   
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            var query = $@"SELECT 
                        BillClassificationId
                        , BC.Name
                        , BC.ChargeType
                        , MA.MainAccountNo
                        , MA.Name as MainAccountName
                        , MA.MainAccountTypeId
                        , MA.MainAccountSubTypeId
                        , MA.WriteOffAccountNo
                    FROM [RATES].[BillClassification] BC
                    JOIN [ACCOUNTING].[MainAccount] MA
                        ON MA.MainAccountNo = BC.MainAccount                        
                    WHERE BillClassificationId = @billingClassificationId ";

            var result = await connection.QueryAsync<dynamic, dynamic, dynamic>(
                query
                , (billClassification, mainAccount) =>
                {
                    var mainAccountForBillClass = new MainAccount(mainAccount.MainAccountNo, mainAccount.MainAccountName, Enumeration.FromValue<MainAccountType>(mainAccount.MainAccountTypeId), Enumeration.FromValue<MainAccountSubType>(mainAccount.MainAccountSubTypeId), mainAccount.WriteOffAccountNo);
                    _transactionRepository.Detach(mainAccountForBillClass);

                    var billClass = new BillClassification(
                        billClassification.BillClassificationId,
                        billClassification.Name,
                        Enumeration.FromValue<ChargeType>(billClassification.ChargeType),
                        mainAccountForBillClass
                    );
                    _transactionRepository.Detach(billClass);

                    return billClass;
                }
                , new { billingClassificationId }, splitOn: "MainAccountNo");

            var billClassification = result.FirstOrDefault();

            return billClassification;
        }
```

Notice here, I had to manually create an instance of "MainAccount" to compose "BillClassification" instance.

**Application Layer/PostTransactionService**

Similarly, later I need to add "LineItem" instances to my "Transaction" instance, and for each of those line items I need to use data provided by "BillingClassificationQueries".

```
 foreach (var item in command.TransactionLineItems)
        {
            var itemBillingCode = await _billingClassificationQueries.GetBillingCode(item.BillingCodeId.Value);
            //_transactionRepository.Detach(itemBillingCode);               

            var lineItem = TransactionLineItem.CreateLineItemForChargeOrCredit(
                transaction,
                account.AccountNumber,
                command.TransactionDate,
                new Money(item.AmountPosted),
                new Money(command.ArBalance),
                "",
                itemBillingCode);

            transaction.AddLineItem(lineItem);
        }
```

Notice the use of "itemBillingCode" which comes from BillingClassificationQueries and whose data I retrieve like this:

**Application Layer/BillClassificationQueries**

```
 var result = await connection.QueryAsync<dynamic, dynamic, dynamic, dynamic, dynamic>(
                 query
                 ,(billingCode, billingCodeMainAccount, billClassification, billClassificationMainAccount) => 
                 {
                     var mainAccountForBillingClass = new MainAccount(
                                 billClassificationMainAccount.BC_MA_MainAccountNo,
                                 billClassificationMainAccount.BC_MA_Name,
                                 Enumeration.FromValue<MainAccountType>(billClassificationMainAccount.BC_MA_MainAccountTypeId),
                                 Enumeration.FromValue<MainAccountSubType>(billClassificationMainAccount.BC_MA_MainAccountSubTypeId),
                                 billClassificationMainAccount.BC_MA_WriteOffAccountNo
                                 );
                     //_transactionRepository.Detach(mainAccountForBillingClass);

                     var mainAccountForBillingCode = new MainAccount(
                                 billingCodeMainAccount.BCD_MA_MainAccountNo,
                                 billingCodeMainAccount.BCD_MA_Name,
                                 Enumeration.FromValue<MainAccountType>(billingCodeMainAccount.BCD_MA_MainAccountTypeId),
                                 Enumeration.FromValue<MainAccountSubType>(billingCodeMainAccount.BCD_MA_MainAccountSubTypeId),
                                 billingCodeMainAccount.BCD_MA_WriteOffAccountNo
                                 );
                    // _transactionRepository.Detach(mainAccountForBillingCode);

                     var result = new BillingCode(
                         billingCode.BCD_BillingCodeId,
                         billingCode.BCD_Name,
                         new BillClassification(
                             billClassification.BC_BillClassificationId,
                             billClassification.BC_Name,
                             Enumeration.FromValue<ChargeType>(billClassification.BC_ChargeTypeId),
                             mainAccountForBillingClass
                             ),
                         mainAccountForBillingCode,
                         new Money(billingCode.BCD_SuggestedAmount)
                         );
                     //_transactionRepository.Detach(result);

                     return result;
                 }
                , new { billingCodeId }, splitOn: "BCD_MA_MainAccountNo, BC_BillClassificationId, BC_MA_MainAccountNo"
                );
```

Again, notice the prescence of MainAccount instance "mainAccountForBillingClass" which will have the same ID (MainAccountNo) as the previously discussed MainAccount instance.

Coming to my problem, when I call `_context.Add(transaction).Entity;` I am getting the following error:

> The instance of entity type 'MainAccount' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'MainAccountNo'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values

I am gessing the issue is the two MainAccount instances "mainAccountForBillClass" from the first query and "mainAccountForBillingClass" from the second query. As you might see in some commented lines, I tried to Detach those instances from the DBContext in below way, but still had the same issue:

```
public void Detach(Entity entity)
    {
        _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
    }
```

Finally my Repo and DBContext are both registered as Scoped (the default life Style)

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITransactionRepository, TransactionRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IBillingClassificationQueries>(sp => new BillingClassificationQueries(builder.Configuration["ConnectionString"].ToString(), sp.GetRequiredService<ITransactionRepository>()));
```

Any recommendations on how to handle this issue?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchinfo/ A minimal example of your problem will make people more likely to answer, for the future :) You have a lot of unrelated/adjacent code and details about your infra in the question

Comment: Why do you have two objects with the same `BCD_MA_MainAccountNo` values? Does it have to be a unique key? You have two separate objects that are identical in values.

Answer (score 0):

The query side should not have any references to the Repository interfaces. Create a new QueryDbContext for the query side and make it read-only like this in its constructor:

```
ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
```

CQRS has come to separate the entire process of queries and commands. In its ideal implementation, your read and write models must differ and cannot reference each other and they must be stored in different storages. So if you are using the weak version of CQRS, at least, you should make a new DbContext for each of them and make the query DbContext read-only. This way, you are assured that no modifications can affect the system through the QueryDbContext.